# how to send post requests body in python script

Tags: python, api, python-requests

I am sending a post request from Angular-4 and its working perfectly, here how i done it

```
demo_service(cate, review) {
  let headers = new Headers();
  headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');

  return this.http_obj.post("http://ns519750.ip-158-69-23.net:8100/func/demo/",JSON.stringify( {
    "category": cate,
    "review": review
  }),{headers: headers}).map((response: Response) => response.json());
}
```

Now I am trying to send the same request from python script like that

```
userdata = {'category': "laptop2" + '/', 'review':str(reviewData[0].SNR_Review)}
r = requests.post('http://ns519750.ip-158-69-23.net:8100/func/demo/',  data=userdata)
print('rrrr    ', r.content)
print('rrrr    ', r)
```

But it giving me the KeyError, Can anybody tell how does body of post request pass in python script.

Down below is the error log

```
File "/home/amad/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 41, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/home/amad/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 249, in _legacy_get_response
    response = self._get_response(request)
  File "/home/amad/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 187, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "/home/amad/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 185, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/home/amad/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/views/decorators/csrf.py", line 58, in wrapped_view
    return view_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/amad/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py", line 68, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 483, in dispatch
    response = self.handle_exception(exc)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 443, in handle_exception
    self.raise_uncaught_exception(exc)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 480, in dispatch
    response = handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rest_framework/decorators.py", line 52, in handler
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/amad/Desktop/djangoshopnroar/userReviews/views.py", line 176, in Calculate_VendorReviewsScore
    r = requests.post('http://ns519750.ip-158-69-23.net:8100/func/demo/',  data=userdata, headers=headers)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/api.py", line 109, in post
    return request('post', url, data=data, json=json, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/api.py", line 50, in request
    response = session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
TypeError: request() got an unexpected keyword argument 'category'
```

Comment: Add the exact error in the question, might help us understand whats going wrong

Comment: I updated the question please check it thanks

Comment: Your code works with Python 3 and requests 2.17.3. Which version are you using ?

Comment: The top part of the traceback is missing. It does not contain any of your own code lines.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, use the `json` parameter to `request.post()` your data as a json instead of a form post, like you do in your JS:

```
r = requests.post('http://ns519750.ip-158-69-23.net:8100/func/demo/',  json=userdata)
```

However, I cannot find a relationship between your python code and the exception you posted. Is it the exact same code that gives you an exception ?

Comment: It only restrict to send json data only. What if someone want to send raw data?

Comment: then you can use the `data` parameter instead. It can take a `bytes` with the raw data to send as body. https://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/api/#main-interface